# Google Maps API delay in loading variable

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to use the Google Maps API to fetch the city name from a zipcode. This is not my strength (I'm more of a PHP person), so I am using sample code I found, with some modifications suggested by a friend.

The problem is, after I call the function my global variable with the city name is still at it's initialized value of null.  If, however, I do an alert with this value, the rest of the processing suddenly has the correct value loaded! I tried putting in a time delay to see if Google was just slow in returning the value, but it makes no difference.

Here's the function:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
function getGoogleAddress(zipcode) {
    //var gcity = "N/A"; switch to using global var defined above
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zipcode}, function (result, status) {
        for (var component in result[0]['address_components']) {
            for (var i in result[0]['address_components'][component]['types']) {
                if (result[0]['address_components'][component]['types'][i] == "locality") {
                    gcity = result[0]['address_components'][component]['short_name'];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And this is where it's called from...including the alert and the pause:

```
        gcity="";
        getGoogleAddress(form.zip.value);
        var holdcity = gcity;
        var date = new Date();
        var curDate = null;
        do { curDate = new Date(); }
        while(curDate-date < 2000);
        alert(gcity);
```

As I said, the alert returns null, but the rest of the processing has the proper city name in gcity.  If I leave out the alert, the rest of the processing fails because gcity is null.

Any advice or suggestions are greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Hint: the "A" in ajax stands for "asynchronous." This question is asked, in one form or another, at least 5 times daily.

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous.

The `function (result, status) {` is only executed when Google's servers have responded.  The rest of your `getGoogleAddress` function doesn't wait for that, but exits, and Javascript continues execution at `var holdcity = gcity`.

The reason it works *after* the `alert`, is that by then, Google will have responded, and the gcity variable will have been executed.

Possible solution:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
function getGoogleAddress(zipcode, successFunction) {
    //var gcity = "N/A"; switch to using global var defined above
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zipcode}, function (result, status) {
        for (var component in result[0]['address_components']) {
            for (var i in result[0]['address_components'][component]['types']) {
                if (result[0]['address_components'][component]['types'][i] == "locality") {
                    var gcity = result[0]['address_components'][component]['short_name'];
                    successFunction(gcity);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And this is where it's called from...including the alert and the pause:

```
    getGoogleAddress(form.zip.value, function (holdcity) {
        var date = new Date();
        var curDate = null;
        do { curDate = new Date(); }
        while(curDate-date < 2000);
        alert(holdcity);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you...the alert now works, but immediately after the initial problem reoccurs. I reassign holdcity to my gcity variable, and it is blank unless I do an alert.

Comment: I'm guessing you're writing code _outside_ the getGoogleAddress function?  That's not going to work, since that code will be executed BEFORE the anonymous `function(holdcity)`.  You need to put your code where you use `gcity` in a separate function, and call that from getGoogleAddress.